# Markup for RentalCarReservation not shows in Gmail but in inbox.google yes

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, json-ld, google-schemas

I'm looking to add [`RentalCarReservation`](https://schema.org/RentalCarReservation) to the consumer-side confirmation.

With the templates of the documentation official It don't shows nothing, but in the inbox.gmail yes.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

@Jordi Salom, *RentalCarReservation* will not integrate with Gmail like *FlightReservation*. However, it will integrate with [Inbox](https://inbox.google.com) and [Now](https://www.google.com/landing/now/#cards/).

Here's a Now card that was triggered after I sent myself a test email. Your consumer's will see an added benefit with the cards.

[image]